# How can I use the value from my timer to make a scoring system in my game? - Java

Tags: java, timer

what I am trying to achieve is retrieve the time in my timer so I can calculate the amount of points the user gets in my game, however I am new to Java and can't seem to make it work. I have tried various different solutions but didn't think it fit with my issue. I don't really know how to retrieve the time in the timer as a value to use, so I did the following:

```
public class TimerPanel extends JPanel{

    private Timer timer;
    private Timer timer2;
    private long startTime = -1;
    public long duration = 30000;
    public boolean paused = false;
    public long remainingDuration = 0;
    long clockTime;
    
    private JLabel label;

    public void stopTimer() {
        
        this.timer.stop();
    }
    
    
    
    public void startTimer() {
        
        if (!timer.isRunning()) {

            if(paused) {
                duration = remainingDuration;
                paused = false;
            }
            else {
                duration = 30000;
            }
            
            startTime = -1;
            timer.start();
      }         
    }
    
    public void pauseTimer() {
        paused = true;
        this.timer.stop();
    }
    
    public int getCurrentTime() {
        return (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(remainingDuration);
    }
    
    
    public TimerPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime < 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                clockTime = now - startTime;
                if (clockTime >= duration) {
                    clockTime = duration;
                    timer.stop();
                    duration = 30000;
                
                    
                }
                
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                remainingDuration = duration - clockTime;
                label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));

                //Below is my attempt at making a score out of the time left

                long timeused = remainingDuration - duration;
                long equation = timeused / 30;
                long equation2 = equation / 2;
                long equation3 = 1 - equation2;
                long equation4 = equation3 * 1000;

            }
        });
        
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        label = new JLabel("00:30");
        label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 13));
        add(label);
        
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(50, 50);
    }

}
```

On the bottom I tried calculating the points, but I don't even know if it works, since this timer panel class is in a different class than my JFrame, so when I try and change the text in the JLabel that is in my JFrame, it doesn't recognize the equation4 variable since it is in a different class. This is possibly very confusing so I will try and clear up any doubts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you change this method? I'm also not familiar with the Timer class you're using, so I don't know what the ActionListener is actually listening for.

```
public TimerPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime < 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                clockTime = now - startTime;
                if (clockTime >= duration) {
                    clockTime = duration;
                    timer.stop();
                    duration = 30000;
                
                    
                }
                
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                remainingDuration = duration - clockTime;

                //Below is my attempt at making a score out of the time left

                long timeused = remainingDuration - duration;
                long equation = timeused / 30;
                long equation2 = equation / 2;
                long equation3 = 1 - equation2;
                long equation4 = equation3 * 1000;
//difference is below
                label.setText(""+equation4);


            }
        });
        
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        label = new JLabel("00:30");
        label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 13));
        add(label);
        
    }
```